# How to change the text cursor color in Notepad++

Tags: notepad++

If i apply a dark theme in Notepad++ the cursor stays black and therefore the cursor disappears when it shows as textmarker into the background.

Is there an options for changing that?

In sublimeText2 the text cursor is white.

Image: (http://msdn.microsoft.com/dynimg/IC210312.png)

Answer (score 9):

Yes, `settings - styler configurator - global styles - carat colour`

Edit

To include discussion below, this changes the carat, not the mouse pointer or cursor as those are handled by the OS.

[image: pointers]

Comment: That is the carat that shows where you would input text, not the cursor you move with your mouse.

Comment: The mouse pointer settings are based on the OS

Comment: But in SublimeText2 they have made the cursor white? If that is the case, I find it strange that you would choose a dark theme in Notepad++.

Comment: @KevinSimper my mouse is the same in both sublimetext2 and notepad++ as well as all my other windows. I'm using Windows Black (system scheme), which is a black mouse (pointer, cursor) with white outline. The outline shows up better on dark windows than light windows.

Comment: @KevinSimper as seen [here](http://flic.kr/p/faRKHu)

Comment: Even when using _Windows Black (large) system scheme_ mouse pointer, the text cursor is difficult to locate in a dark theme N++ for default stylers (given up on other themes as over the years Windows Updates continue to sporadically knock it back to default by removing N++ config files- but that's another story). Choosing a yellow colour for the caret works well. :) .

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the OS.   Go to 'mouse pointers' in Control Panel, 
click on the 'text select', then 'browse', and choose 'beam_r'

Comment: Now available is `beam_rm` and `beam_rl` for even larger cursors. Alternatively consider any of the large or extra large pointer schemes.

Answer (score 1):

I went to control panel and to the mouse where there is an option for additional items. I clicked on the pointer and changed it to black. At least I can see that when it is in notepad

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue and what worked for me was going to the Mouse Pointer Settings in Windows OS Control Panel and then changing the pointer size to 2.